# Target one line only in vim for a text substitution

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a way in vi(m) to target one specific line in a file for a string substitution?

I need to frequently add SSL SHA fingerprints from Web servers to my Mercurial .hgrc. I can grab the required signature from Chrome pretty easily by double-clicking the padlock and looking at the certificate details, but I get the sig with space delimiters rather than the colon delimiters desired by Mercurial

```
06 32 1C C5 8A 49 77 85 C5 89 6F 67 75 96 F0 43 77 96 EB 90
```

Example from [Google Code](https://code.google.com).

Is there a way to:

1. Copy said fingerprint to my clipboard
2. Edit my .hgrc with vi(m)
3. Go into insert mode to paste said fingerprint
4. Target just that line with a

   :s/ /:/g
5. Save the file

Right now I can paste the fingerprint into a new file, do the substitution, and pull it into my .hgrc with a *:r filename*, but that's an extra step that I wouldn't mind skipping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

Move your cursor to the line you want to mod, and do this:

.s/ /:/g

The '.' in front of the substitute command tells vi(m) that you only want to mod the current line.

Ref: http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/search_and_replace_with_vi_part_1.htm

Comment: After reading the link you posted I see that the dot is not required. My actual original expression works fine, since "The default range of lines is the current line only." I think I was misunderstanding reach of "g", figuring it would replace all the spaces in the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert it after line N :

```
:N put =substitute(@+, ' ', '', 'g')
```

End of file: N=$ ; beginning of file: N=0. @+ is the clipboard register (when GUI is running).

Comment: Nice. Only downside is the extra step of having to know the explicit line number. But at least I see it displayed in the lower right of the editor.

Comment: you can state `.` or `/pattern/` instead of N to refer to current line or next line matching pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `:s/ /:/g` will do fine.

The `:substitute` command works only on the current line by default.

The `/g` global modifier means to replace all matches in the specified range, not the whole file.)

Comment: (I know you [already](http://superuser.com/questions/316691/target-one-line-only-in-vim-for-a-text-substitution?rq=1#comment339446_316698) found that out, but I thought having this as an explicit answer may help future readers save a few seconds.)

Answer (score -1):

are you meaning to do this?

```
echo "06 32 1C C5 8A 49 77 85 C5 89 6F 67 75 96 F0 43 77 96 EB 90" >> <filename>
```

Comment: Not really. Looking for answer that involves vim.